# Read datasource from a database or a file and based on API identifier, save data in the database? Which tool to use?

Tags: spring, database, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, datasource

In a Spring Boot Application, there is a method mapped with a POST API for posting certain data in database. The issue is based on API URL parameter, data source will change.

Like the API is: **{baseURL}/api/{someIdentifier}/addUser**

Now, there is another file or consider a database which maps *Database Connection Strings* (like Datasource, Username, password, driver) to this **{someIdentifier}**. There could be a lot of such identifiers (corresponding to which there could be multiple databases and their parameters).

Now when this API gets hit, based on this identifier there will be a method which will fetch connection strings, make the connection and then it should save the data in that database. On every API, creating a connection is not feasible.

Can anyone please suggest which tool or technology can be helpful for solving this problem, especially using Spring Boot.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [`AbstractRoutingDataSource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/AbstractRoutingDataSource.html).

From its documentation:

> Abstract DataSource implementation that routes getConnection() calls to one of various target DataSources based on a lookup key. The latter is usually (but not necessarily) determined through some thread-bound transaction context.

Comment: Thank you! I believe it's going to be of help!